Graph of topologist's sine curve as the inverse image of $\{0\}$
In the book I am reading, the author mentions that the graph of $\sin(1/x) $ i.e. $S:=\{(x,\sin(1/x))\mid x\in X\}$ where $X=(0, 1]$ is closed in $X\times \mathbb R$ as

$S$ is the inverse image of $\{0\}$ under the function $q=p_2-f\circ p_1,$

where $p_1, p_2$ are projection maps of $X\times \mathbb R $ with $p_1:X\times \mathbb R\to X$ and $p_2: X\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R. $
However, I am not able to see how $S$ is the inverse image of $\{0\}$ under $q.$
If it is so, then $q(S) =0.$ That would mean $p_2(S) \setminus f\circ q_1(S) =\{0\}.$ But aren't $p_2(S)=\{\sin (1/x)\mid x\in X\}$ and $f\circ p_1(S) =f((0, 1]) =\{\sin (1/x)\mid x\in X\}$ which means both are the same sets and hence the set difference doesn't lead to $\{0\}$? Perhaps I am confusing and missing something. I would appreciate any insight on this.

When checking $q(S)$, you must check element-wise. For every element $s \in S$, $q(s) = 0$. Hence have $S \subseteq q^{-1}({0})$.

Thanks @Agilan for the response.

Take a point $(x,y)$ in the plane. $q(x,y)=0$ means
$$
0=p_2(x,y)-f\circ p_1(x, y)\\
f\circ p_1(x,y)=p_2(x,y)\\
f(x)=y
$$
So $(x,y)\in S$ means $y=f(x)$, which is to say, the point is of the form $(x, f(x))$. This is exactly how the graph of $f$ is defined.

That's helpful, Arthur. Wouldn't by that logic, every graph of say, a real-valued function would be closed? Would it be right to generalize this?

@User1865345 Every graph of a continuous real-valued function is closed, yes. The two functions $f$ and $q$ are either both continuous or they are both discontinuous. And if $q$ is discontinuous, the inverse image of ${0}$ doesn't have to be closed.
